# WPF ContextMenu and MenuItem Cannot set OverridesDefaultStyle property in the default Style WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, contextmenu

I'm trying to create library with components that have an extended appearance configuration.
Instead of creating more styles and templates, I can inherit style from default style for custom component, and override few values.

I created CustomizableContextMenu and CustomizableMenuItem classes inherited from default ContextMenu and MenuItem and extended them by additional constructor. For example for CustomizableContextMenu.

```
static CustomizableContextMenu()
{
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomizableContextMenu),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomizableContextMenu)));
}
```

Styles and templates are in separate files that are referenced in the file "Themes/Generic.xaml".

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/FluentControls;component/Themes/CustomizableContextMenuStyle.xaml"/>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/FluentControls;component/Themes/CustomizableMenuItemStyle.xaml"/>  
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource CustomizableContextMenuStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type components:CustomizableContextMenu}"/>
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource CustomizableMenuItemStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type components:CustomizableMenuItem}"/>
```

Until I try to make style and template in the same app (without overriding DefaultStyleKeyProperty) and making reference to style in MainWindow.xaml everything works fine. But now (except other components such Button, TextBox, ComboBox, CheckBox, etc.) I have a problem with it.

I'm trying to create CustomizableButton (the same problem appears when I'm using standard Button) with CustomizableContextMenu and CustomizableMenuItem, but it didn't work. The message I've got from the IDE was "**Cannot set OverridesDefaultStyle property in the default Style**"

This is implementation code of CustomizableContextMenu.

```
<Components:CustomizableButton
    ...
    Content="I have ContextMenu!">

    <Button.ContextMenu>
        <Components:CustomizableContextMenu
            Background="#C0000000"
            BorderBrush="#C00078D7"
            BorderThickness="1"
            Foreground="White">

           <Components:CustomizableMenuItem
               Background="#C0000000"
               BorderBrush="#C00078D7"
               Foreground="White"
               Header="Item Test 1"
               InputGestureText="Ctrl+1"
               Margin="0,1"/>

        </Components:CustomizableContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Components:CustomizableButton>
```

It's possible to do it in easy way, or not? And I must remove override of DefaultStyleKeyProperty, and import style in the traditional way to MainWindow.xaml and use it by setting property in component definition?

Comment: Are you setting the `OverridesDefaultStyle` property in your `Style`?

Comment: Yes, <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />

Comment: So remove this setter?

Comment: Yes, removing this setter helps

Comment: Great. I posted an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the following `<Setter>` from the default style:

```
<Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
```

Since the style in `themes/generic.xaml` *is* the default style by defintion, it cannot override another default style.